# Error 0Xc0000005 in a program that tokenizes a list of numbers using strtok

Tags: c, strtok, strcpy

I am currently programming a c program which gets text files as input.
in every line I am getting a known ahead n float numbers, separated with comma.
example line:

```
0.92,0.21,0.98,1
0.23,0.37,0.29,-1
0.22,0.35,0.63,1
0.14,0.89,0.78,-1
0.26,0.42,0.67,1
0.01,0.77,0.92,-1
0.67,0.12,0.59,-1
```

I need to put the numbers in an array.
here is part of my code:

```
strcpy(tmp_line,strtok (line,","));
for(int j = 0;j < n + 1; j++)
{
            vec.arr[j] = atof(tmp_line);
            strcpy(tmp_line,strtok (NULL, ","));
}
```

I don't know why, when I use clion, in the end of the loop the program just stops running.
when I use codeblocks, it give this message

> PROCCES RETURNED  (0Xc0000005)

which means we are using memory that we cannot access.

help? anybody?

---

a few notes:
`vec` is a Vector struct. a Vector struct contains a 75 long array and a (int) tag. we use the first n cells of the array and put the tag (+ or - 1) in the n+1 cell (and the tag part).

`tmp_line` is a char array contains the current line.

Comment: If you have `n` numbers, you should not assign `n+1` array elements..

Comment: Please add a complete (small) snippet of code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Need full code-- in particular your declaration of line, tmp_line, vec.arr

Comment: Your title is not helpful. Consider changing it to something descriprive, like "error 0Xc0000005 in a program that reds a kist of numbers".

Comment: @n.m. I borrowed your words :)

Answer (score 1):

As I see your code, the problem appears to be in

```
 strcpy(tmp_line,strtok (NULL, ","));
```

inside the `for` loop. Once finished tokenizing, `strtok()` will return `NULL` which is considered invalid parameter for `strcpy()`.

You should break down the statement, collect the return value of `strtok()` into a temporary pointer variable, check against NULL and if not NULL, perform the `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you need to look at the documentation for `strtok`, first of all. What `strtok` returns is a `char *` to the next token. On the first call, it stashes the string, then on each call after that with NULL as the argument it gets the next string.

so, the canonical code would be

```
char * my_string = "this is a blank delimited string";
char * tok;
tok = strtok(my_string, " ");
while(tok != NULL){
  /* do something with the string */
  printf("Token: %s\n", tok);
  tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

It's hard to tell where your code is going wrong, but at the very least that `strcpy` is unnecessary.  It's also, from what you're saying, a problem that you're doing a `strcpy` on top of the string that contains the current line, which means you are mashing the string that `strtok` is trying to tokenize; this is probably the source of the memory error.

Comment: Passing a string literal to `strtok()` is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Nonsense.  In fact the example in the canonical POSIX man page uses a string constant. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtok.html

Comment: Just because the manual you happen to find on the internet contains a wrong example, it doesn't make it right. Perhaps, you should read either C standard or search on the internet before emphatically calling it *nonsense*.

Comment: Look again. POSIX standard.

Comment: So what? POSIX documentation writers never make a mistake? What's your point?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop counter is probably wrong. You say you only have `n` floats but it loops for `n+1` times. You don't need to count the number of floats either. 
You don't need `tmp_line` either. As you tokenize, you can count the number of floats. So it boils down to this:

```
j = 0;
for(char *tmp = strtok (line,","); tmp ; tmp = strtok (NULL, ","))
{
   vec.arr[j] = atof(tmp);
   j++;
}
// 'j' number of tokens found in this line
```

This would also save you from worrying about whether you pass valid strings to `strcpy()` (as you don't need at all :)

There are other things you need to consider:

1) How to handle if the `line` contains uneven number of floats.
2) Whether `arr` has enough storage for as many floats in each line.
3) `atof()` doesn't report errors on conversion. You would be advised to use `strtof()` or `strtod()` for detecting conversion failures.